# Accordion menu state select on page load

Tags: jquery, accordion

Hi all please help me out here.

I have this accordion menu http://jsfiddle.net/manidf/nMPrV/

what i would like to happen is for the third TAB to be open onPageLoad. and not the the first tab is it is now. How do i add the active class to the third tab.

Any pointers would be great. I have had a look around but they all seem more complicated than what i am after.

thanks.
Manny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide the others except for the third.

The proof is in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMPrV/7/

If you're wondering why your text isn't coming up red (as per your CSS), it's because you have this selector:

```
$("#viptables ul li:first a").addClass("current");
```

But you have this html:

```
<ul>
    <li>Link one</li>  <!-- Not actually a link -->
    ...
</ul>
```

Note the lack of an anchor (a) tag....

Comment: wow thank you so much, did not even see that i had not put link in there, thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just manually set the LI you want to have the `class="active"` to start. `display:none;` the rest.